# Array of multiple strings possible? Or just array of characters for one string? XGetWindowProperty on atom's where we know a string is returned

Tags: x11

When I do XGetWindowProperty on atoms that return strings, such as `_NET_WM_NAME`, `WM_CLASS`, `WM_NAME`. They are returning an array of characters. However when I ask for long or short types like `_NET_WM_PID` it returns an array of longs, for the PID its just 1 element array, the `nitems_return` argument is populated with number of elements returned in the array, so for PID its 1. But for the string atoms, the `nitems_return` hold number of characters returned.

I tested convenience function of `XGetWMName` and this set the `nitems` field of `XTextProperty` to number of characters returned which matches `XGetWindowProperty`, so I was wondering, is there ever a chance that XGetWindowProperty can returned number of elements in array like for long and short? OR is there only ever just one string associated with those string atoms?

[docs on XGetWindowProperty](http://www.xfree86.org/4.4.0/XGetWindowProperty.3.html)

Thanks

Comment: `STRING` is a single string type, `TEXT` and `COMPOUND_TEXT` are for arrays of strings. See `XmbTextPropertyToTextList` and `XmbTextListToTextProperty`.

Comment: Thanks @n.m. so does that mean XGetWindowProperty returns TEXT?

Comment: XGetWindowProperty returns a property. A property consists of format (8/16/32), value (an array of 8/16/32 bit quantities) and type (an atom). The application interprets the array according to the format and type. One possible type is STRING, another one is TEXT, another one is COMPOUND_TEXT.

Comment: But @n.m. i thought 8/16/32 meant char, short, or long? and only if char it has chance to be string/text/compound_text? i interperted this from the dos page: "If the returned format is 8, the returned data is represented as a char array. If the returned format is 16, the returned data is represented as a short array and should be cast to that type to obtain the elements. If the returned format is 32, the returned data is represented as a long array and should be cast to that type to obtain the elements." from here: http://www.xfree86.org/4.4.0/XGetWindowProperty.3.html

Comment: That's true, why does it matter in your case? It is normally 8 for strings but you shouldn't care. You just pass everything to XmbTextPropertyToTextList and it takes care of whatever format you get.

Comment: Ah I'll look into that I didn't know that. Right now based on format I'm casting it to long or to short and then iterating through the array. If its format of string then i just read string. Here: https://github.com/Noitidart/_scratchpad/blob/master/ScreensaverWindowExists%20addon%20test%20template.js#L788 I'll now research this XmbTextPropertyToTextList thanks very much!